# lualatex -jobname=foo don't produce foo.pdf

Tags: lualatex-dev

I'am struggling with unexpected behaivior of my favorite Tex engine `Lualatex`. I want to set jobname:

```
lualatex test.tex --job-name=foo
```

The Hello word code is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
  Hello world
\end{document}
```

But the Lualatex produce pdf with name test.pdf instead of foo.pdf. What is going on? I was able to google one relevant topic *"lualatex not setting filename as jobname when using \input in command line"* on tug.org see [link](https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2010-August/001986.html), but it is posted in the year 2010. Xelatex works well. I am using updated Miktex (LuaHBTeX, Version 1.14.0 (MiKTeX 22.1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass any options like `-jobname` first, before the name of the TeX file. So you have to run

```
lualatex -jobname=foo test.tex
```

Comment: But for xelatex and pdflatex, the order shown in my question works. I thought all Tex engines behaved the same.